# ruby code + string with capybara text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I have this tag `<p>` with the next content:

```
<p id="post_example"> <%= t (".for_example_type") %> <strong><%= post.title %></strong></p>
```

In my integration test:

```
it "should have example post" do
  should have_selector "#post_example", :text => "For example, type #{post.title}"
end

1) Index page should have example post
     Failure/Error: should have_selector "#post_example", :text => "For example, type #{post.title}"
       expected #has_selector?("#post_example", {:text=>"For example, type Post number 10"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/posts_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 3.8 seconds
6 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/posts_spec.rb:25 # Index page should have example post


Randomized with seed 5480
```

**Is it possible pass to capybara `:text` a mix of ruby code and text/string?**

Comment: Have you posted valid snippets? Because, in the test declaration, text contains #{post.title} but in the error output contains #{post.occupation}

Answer (score 1):

Its already the case. Look at your stack trace:

```
expected #has_selector?("#post_example", {:text=>"For example, type Post number 10"})
```

Text has been interpreted: `:text=>"For example, type Post number 10"`

Comment: With `it "should have example post" do
      should have_selector("#post_example", {:text=>"For example, type Post number 10"})
    end` I get the error `expected #has_selector?("#post_example", {:text=>"For example, type Post number 10"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/posts_spec.rb:26:in 'block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try matching the following text:

```
should have_selector "#post_example", :text => "For example, type <strong>#{post.title}</strong>"
```